# $\lim_{x\to 0} (e^x + 3x)^{1/x} \neq (\lim_{x\to 0} e^x + \lim_{x\to 0} 3x)^{\lim_{x\to 0} (1/x)}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> Why is $$\lim_{x\to 0} (e^x + 3x)^{1/x} \neq (\lim_{x\to 0} e^x + \lim_{x\to 0} 3x)^{\lim_{x\to 0} (1/x)}$$

I stumbled open this problem but I cant seem to find why I'm not to move the limit into the power and into the brackets.

Comment: Plz use Tex formatting. Put symbols between $.

Comment: Why do you think you can move it to the power?

Comment: [Here's a tutorial in MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Since $\lim_{x\to 0} (1/x)$ doesn't exist, there is nothing to show.

Comment: The kind of process where you are moving limit into smaller parts of a bigger expression is possible but in a very controlled manner via the "algebra of limits". Such process is also possible in case of exponential expressions but only when limit of base is positive and that of exponent is finite. Clearly your example does not meet this criteria.

Answer (score 2):

In general, if moving a limit into the power and the base would result in something in the form
$$1^\infty$$
then you *can't do it.* For example, consider the famous limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(1+\frac{1}{n}\bigg)^n$$
If you moved the limit into the base and the power, you would get the answer $1$. But as you know, this limit is equal to $e$.

Here is a better way to tackle your problem:
$$\lim_{x\to 0} (e^x+3x)^\frac{1}{x}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0} \exp \ln(e^x+3x)^\frac{1}{x}$$
$$=\exp \bigg(\lim_{x\to 0} \ln(e^x+3x)^\frac{1}{x}\bigg)$$
$$=\exp \bigg(\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln(e^x+3x)}{x}\bigg)$$
Then, using L'Hopital,
$$=\exp \bigg(\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\frac{e^x+3}{e^x+3x}}{1}\bigg)$$
$$=\exp \bigg(\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^x+3}{e^x+3x}\bigg)$$
$$=\exp \bigg(\frac{1+3}{1+0}\bigg)$$
$$=\exp 4$$
$$=e^4$$

Does this help?